# door like hinge in a div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

**Description :**

I have a page that has metro styled tabs like in Windows 8. Right now user can click on any tab and go to a certain page. What I want, is, that when user clicks on any tab it should hinge backwards a little and should come back when click is released like when we open a door and then close it.

**What have I tried :**

I have tried to add rotation along Y  axis (z axis in general) but it doesnt quite works the way it should.

**Any found help :**

I saw a couple of tutorials that teaches on how to rotate an image completely in 3D but some are a bit complicated and some have code longer than the actual problem. Can any one help me?

Comment: Could you add some code here, or even better, paste the link to a fiddle you create (http://www.jsfiddle.com)

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uzthcu0v/1/)

@ctwheels check out the problem demo it does hinge back but doesnt come back when mouse is released

Comment: Things you need to look for are mouse events such `mousedown`, `mouseup` to add the classes you need. As for the animation part look for the `perspective` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/uzthcu0v/24/

### css

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    perspective: 150px;
    perspective-origin: 0 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

#pom {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;

}

.rotate{ transform: rotateY(25deg); }
```

Comment: Haha, you just made me waste a little time on this, it's oddly fun to do

Comment: Here is a fiddle that includes mouseout and unselectable text (as I imagine you'd want for a tab) http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/uzthcu0v/25/

Comment: Just perfect !! Excellent :) a little problem there is the text becomes a little blur when the div rotates ... can u fix that ??

Comment: For the blur fix, what about scaling the text down from a larger size, it might help? `font-size: 200px;` and `-webkit-transform: scale(.075);` after you wrap the text in a span and give it a class or id

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm right, and I can't remember the source, but I've heard something about the text blurring due to it being placed on half a pixel if that makes sense. Perhaps you can find something from there?

Comment: I think it blurs because the browser interprets the font as a texture when it manipulates it in transform

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/uzthcu0v/26/

I didn't use javascript, just css3 3d effects:

```
#pom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid #444444 3px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#pom:active {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
```